# Cannot delete namespace in XSLT if statement using <code>

Tags: xml, xslt

I know that this question might be a very basic and common one (some of you say that it is questioned everyday). But I am very new to XSLT, and I really really need your help :(

I need to transform an XML to XML using XSLT

The input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="XMLNS-A" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xsi:schemaLocation="XMLNS-A http://schema.com/2.13.0/SyncItemMaster.xsd" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.13.0">
<ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Cost</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
        </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
</DataArea>
```

I tried the XSLT as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:my="XMLNS-A"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:Classification/my:Codes">
    <xsl:variable name="service2"select="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:ServiceIndicator"/>
    <xsl:variable name="type2"          select="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:Classification/my:Codes/my:Code"/>
    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($service2='true' and $type2='Cost')">
                <xsl:text>Purchased</xsl:text>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="ServiceIndicator">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$service2" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Code>
</xsl:template>
```

But now, I have this result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="XMLNS-A" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xsi:schemaLocation="XMLNS-A http://schema.com/2.13.0/SyncItemMaster.xsd" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.13.0">
<ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1" xmlns:my="XMLNS-A">Purchased</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
        </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
</DataArea>
```

Note : please ignore the variables, because I already cropped the XML for simplicity.

I am trying to get rid of the namespace on the "Item Types" above.
I have look around for clues in Stackoverflow and tried it, but nothing works.

Please help me..

Thank you

Comment: It usually happens when you dont add your namespaces to your transformation file correctly, it seems like your xsl can not read the namespace correctly and apply it , thats why it shows you the erorr, I had the same issue few days before and fixed it by adding namespace to the xml, xslt file correctly, your XML file is not well-formed (also XSLT), please check it out if everything works correctly before you upload it to here. Tags are not matching etc..

Comment: Hi @Sojimanatsu.Thanks for replying. Is there any good documentation / reference on namespaces that you can share to me? it would be very helpful. Meanwhile, I will try to make the XML and XSLT well-formed. ----Well, because I am very new to XML and XSLT. So please be patient with me :) . Thanks :)

Comment: Dont worry, I was like you once, We learn in time :) I will be waiting for your edited examples to be able to help you more, meanwhile you can check this website http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/

Comment: Thank you so much @Sojimanatsu. Will get back as soon as I read the reference and fix the XML and XSLT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got

```
exclude-result-prefixes="java"
```

Just extend it to

```
exclude-result-prefixes="java my"
```

or

```
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
```

(The value #all requires XSLT 2.0 - you haven't said which version you are using.)

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the advice. I have tried it, and it deletes the namespaces. But it seems that in my middleware, the resulted XML is still having the namespaces. Do you have any other methods? thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, but after 40 years of programming, "X didn't work, let's try something else" has never been part of my way of working. You can't write code by trial and error.

Comment: Noted. Thanks Michael :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i fixed your code by myself i dont know for sure that if you had the same structure. But i tried the solution and there is no such error i found.

XML I used for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:SyncItemMaster xmlns:my="XMLNS-A" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<my:DataArea>
    <my:ItemMaster>
        <my:ItemMasterHeader>
            <my:ServiceIndicator>true</my:ServiceIndicator>
            <my:Classification>
                <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Purchased</Code>
            </my:Classification>
        </my:ItemMasterHeader>
    </my:ItemMaster>
</my:DataArea>
</my:SyncItemMaster>
```

XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="XMLNS-A" 
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:Classification/my:Codes">
<xsl:variable name="service2" select="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:ServiceIndicator"/>
<xsl:variable name="type2"          select="my:Code"/>
<Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($service2='true' and $type2='Cost')">
            <xsl:text>Purchased</xsl:text>              
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="ServiceIndicator">
                <xsl:value-of select="$service2" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</Code>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:SyncItemMaster xmlns:my="XMLNS-A" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<my:DataArea>
    <my:ItemMaster>
        <my:ItemMasterHeader>
            <my:ServiceIndicator>true</my:ServiceIndicator>
            <my:Classification>
                <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1">Purchased</Code>
            </my:Classification>
        </my:ItemMasterHeader>
    </my:ItemMaster>
</my:DataArea>
</my:SyncItemMaster>
```

NOTE: Additionally, you do not have to use all your XPath over and over again, since you already matched your template with your `my:Codes` you are already in that node, and you can just specify the child nodes inside that template.

Comment: Hmmm.. actually I am working on some middleware, and the middleware has an XML translator , so I am having my reference from there. And the result is like I posted before.. I will check on this also.

Comment: I use xml spy and it works correctly. then you can focus on your middleware part :) at least we know now, where the mistake is

Comment: Hi @Sojimanatsu, I have tried Michael's solution also. When I also include the exclude-result-prefixes, on the resulting  the XML the namespace is not showing. But when I run it on the middleware, somehow it still detects the namespaces. at least we already know how to exclude the namespaces from the results :)

By the way, do you know why there are three namespaces (java, XMLNS-A, and the default one) ? what are the java namespace do? haha